# How do I set CONSISTENCY to SERIAL in cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to experiment with lightweight transactions in Cassandra by using `SERIAL` consistency. However, trying to set the consistency level in cqlsh results in an error:

```
cqlsh:learning> CONSISTENCY SERIAL;
Improper CONSISTENCY command.
```

The `WITH CONSISTENCY` statement has been removed from CQL and so I cannot use that. Is there a way to enable serial consistency from cqlsh? Or do I have to do it using a driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONSISTENCY` command should still work in cqlsh.  But [valid values](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html) for this setting are:

- ANY
- ONE
- TWO
- THREE
- QUORUM
- ALL
- LOCAL_QUORUM
- EACH_QUORUM

SERIAL is not in that list, hence the error you are seeing.  There is an open Jira ticket to address this: [CASSANDRA-8051](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8051)

This appears to be a consistency level that has some restrictions around it, thus making this difficult to implement.  The [Consistency Level descriptions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) indicate that:

> You cannot configure this level as a normal consistency level,
>   configured at the driver level using the consistency level field.

The [Java Driver apparently has a specific method](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/queryBuilderOverview.html?scroll=queryBuilderOverview__setting-query-options-querybuilder-api) to set this consistency level:

> The serial consistency level of the query, set with
>   Statement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(), is similar to the consistency
>   level, but only used in queries that have conditional updates. That
>   is, it is only used in queries that have the equivalent of the IF
>   condition in CQL.

Comment: Hmm, that was pretty much my conclusion as well, but I was wondering if there was something I missed. So it looks like I will just have to do it via the driver. Thanks!