# Cassandra Write Timeout Exception on CAS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I have a datacenter us-east-2 and there are three nodes running on it :

```
Datacenter: us-east-2
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                             Rack

UN     18.224.15.224  246.3 KiB  256          0.0%              d17905d7-cf83-4eda-821c-74ccfe921291  2b
UN  3.133.147.118  265.74 KiB  256          0.0%              5429f522-1da1-4239-8359-1a6c528ce5dd  2a
UN  3.132.214.35   269.74 KiB  256          0.0%              76538ea7-a4f7-4370-bab8-03de2e70c5c6  2b
```

I have created a keyspace test :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = {‘class’:’NetworkTopologyStrategy’, ‘us-east-2’:3};
```

I have two tables samplestack and top_table inside test.

I have to use CAS operations for my work and hence there are a couple of UPDATE IF queries (example) :

```
"UPDATE top_table SET top = "+ nextTop +" WHERE id = 0 IF top = "+ currTop;
```

Every single time two of my replicas are exiting stating the error :

`Exception in thread "LockFreeStack3" com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during CAS write query at consistency SERIAL (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)`

Any idea to resolve this? I have read multiple solutions but increasing the timeout does not resolve it. Also, I cannot reduce parallelism and have to incorporate CAS operations for my problem at hand.

I have one thread per replica in my Java code. Setting consistency explicitly to SERIAL also does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set CONSISTENCY to SERIAL in cqlsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591874/how-do-i-set-consistency-to-serial-in-cqlsh)

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using? are you trying to do the same update in each one of the nodes of the cluster? you may be getting into a racing condition

Comment: I am using 3.11.4. A thread is doing the update (there is one thread per replica). So it can pertain to any replica. If I set the consistency level to SERIAL for all operations, don't you think it will be too restrictive? And will I need CAS then?

Comment: setting consistency to SERIAL doesn't work. It produces the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cassandra CAS INSERT timeouts for requests with milliseconds latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747590/cassandra-cas-insert-timeouts-for-requests-with-milliseconds-latency)